# I have right letters in PDF but when i trying to parse it into text i have wrong encoded text

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex, font-encodings, cyrillic

[image]

This picture explain actually the whole problem. I compile pdf file in AUCTeX with UTF-8-dos. And this creates another problem when I'm trying to convert this PDF into DOCX i get exactly this wrong encoded text as I got in Google context menu.

Minimal example:

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\linespread{1.3}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother

\newcounter{SavedCounter}

\graphicspath{{auto/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left = 2cm}
\geometry{right = 1.5cm}
\geometry{top = 1cm}
\geometry{bottom = 2cm}


\newenvironment{numerated}%
{\begin{list}{\arabic{enumi}.}%
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
      \setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}%%
      \usecounter{enumi}}%
  }{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{numerated_1}%
{\begin{list}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}%
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
      \setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}%%
      \usecounter{enumii}}%
  }{\end{list}}




\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \large
    МИНИСТЕРСТВО ОБРАЗОВАНИЯ И НАУКИ\\ РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ

    \textbf{Федеральное агентство по образованию}
    \vspace{0.5cm}

    МОСКОВСКИЙ ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ УНИВЕРСИТЕТ СВЯЗИ И ИНФОРМАТИКИ
    \vspace{0.25cm}

    факультет Радио и Телевидения

    \textsc{Курсовая работа по теме:}\\[15mm]

    {\LARGE Дистанционное Зондирование Земли}
    \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us some code (a MWE) to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TeXnician, done)

Comment: @TeXnician, should I add the tag "cyrillic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepacakge[cp1251]{inputenc}
```

changing emacs encoding to `cp1251` (`windows-1251-dos`) ->

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `cp1251`

and now it's working just fine

[image]